# SSL connections reset with Nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl

I created ssl certs via letsencrypt.  They get created just fine and when I run:

```
openssl x509 -in {ssl_cert} -text -noout
```

It prints out all the appropriate info and looks like everything is good.  The files are owned by root with `0600` permissions.  If, on the other hand, I attempt the same thing from the web:

```
echo | openssl s_client -connect {host}:443
```

I get the following error:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0bytes and written 297bytes
---
New,(NONE),Cipher is(NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression:NONE
Expansion:NONE
---
```

Which leads me to believe that nginx just isn't serving up ssl traffic.  When I try this:

```
nginx -V
```

I get the following (* around important bits)

```
nginx version: nginx/1.1.19
*TLS SNI support enabled*
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --with-debug --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_stub_status_module *--with-http_ssl_module* --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-ipv6 --with-sha1=/usr/include/openssl --with-md5=/usr/include/openssl --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/nginx-echo --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.1.19/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module
```

netstat tells me that nginx is running.

```
$ sudo netstat -an | grep 443
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     8443
```

Since nginx is built with all the ssl support it needs (I think) and my vhost is setup to use ssl and the cert is right... I can't figure out why it would just cut communication when ssl connections come in.  I tried wiresharking the traffic and the client sends an ssl "Client Hello" and gets sent back a RST...

I should point out that I have several vhosts setup on this server and all of them exhibit the exact same behavior.  So I'm guessing it's something more general, but my nginx vhost stuff is below:

I've setup my nginx conf file (only pertinent bits shown):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name {server name};

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server
{
        listen 443 ssl;

        server_name {server name};

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate {path to certs}/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key {path to certs}/privkey.pem;

        ssl_session_timeout 5m;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
        ssl_ciphers'EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS +RC4 RC4';


        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
}
```

So I am *pretty sure* all that stuff is not the problem.  When I try to hit the website

Comment: What happens if you provide a server name: `openssl s_client -connect {host}:443 -servername {host}`?

Comment: What does nginx's log say about the connection?  Have you checked with `netstat` that nginx is actually listening on 443?  Also, I think there are supposed to be spaces between the `ssl_protocols` but that would probably cause an obvious error.

Comment: I'll update my post, but to answer questions: netstat says nginx is listening on 443, thank you for reminding me to mention that.  And something happened with my copy paste... there are spaces between the ssl_protocols

Comment: If I add the `-servername {host}` to the openssl command nothing changes, although that's a great check... no dice.

Comment: What happens if you comment out the `ssl_protocols` and `ssl_ciphers` configs, for now, to rule out the possibility of them causing the issue (or not)?  Specifically, your `ssl_ciphers` value does not appear to be formatted per the [nginx `ssl_ciphers` docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_ciphers), which uses colons between cipher names, not spaces.

Comment: Nginx 1.1.19 is four years old, have you considered updating Nginx?

Comment: Turns out the ciphers weren't a problem, I tried commenting them out, no such luck.  Great catch though I should probably make them match the spec docs (thank you also for those links).

Comment: @Tim I didn't realize how old it was because I was just upgrading whatever was in the default repo.  I started using the stable release ppa for nginx and upgraded straight to 1.8.1 turns out that fixed it.  Totally broke my php sites... but I fixed that too per this guy: http://beutelevision.com/blog2/2013/08/26/nginx-with-php-fpm-generating-blank-page/ So all is well that ends well... but I don't like that the only solution was to upgrade to a version not in the OS default ppa's...

Comment: You may have been able to fix it some other way, but maybe you need a better repository if it provides software that old. Amazon Linux has the same problem, but nothing quite that old. I'll make my suggestion an answer so the question can be marked as done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx 1.1.19 is four years old, the solution is likely to upgrade to the latest version of Nginx.

Comment: This solved my problem but if anyone can extrapolate about what was fixed in nginx from 1.1.19 to 1.8.1 that might have caused this or a work around that'd be great information to have documented.

Comment: I looked through the release notes. There have been dozens of changes and fixes to SSL over the past four years, it would be difficult to pin it down to one individual change. http://nginx.org/en/CHANGES

Comment: I looked through too, there wasn't anything that looked real promising as the culprit...